# Problems with gridlayout with buttons in Android

Tags: c#, android

I was wondering how to format buttons so they all show up on the screen instead of going off it? I have a 10x10 grid and also want them compressed together with no spacing in-between. I'm currently writing this in Visual StudiOS   with Xamarin.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    GridLayout gl = (GridLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.GridLayout1);
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    Button[] cells = new Button[99];
    var i = 0;
    foreach (Button b in cells)
    {
        cells[i] = new Button(this);
        gl.AddView(cells[i]);
        i++;
    }
}}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="10"
android:rowCount="10"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" />
using System;
using Android.App; 

using Android.Content; 

using Android.Runtime; 
using Android.Views; 
using Android.Widget; 
using Android.OS;

Namespace App3 {

[Activity(Label = "App3", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
Public class MainActivity : Activity
 {
```

What I'm getting right now.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkBjF.png

Comment: Please be specific with your issue, you are getting a grid layout but there are spaces in between buttons but you do not need them is it?

Comment: yes, i cant get all 10 buttons on the horizontal row. i thought that android:layout_width="match_parent" might do it but it seems not. i have an imgur photo linked in the post of what i am getting currently.

Comment: Have you tried using horizontal scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

Try by using horizontal scroll view as shown below this might help you:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- Your content here -->

     </HorizontalScrollView>
```